# Creating a new tensor based on the old

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

a = np.array([0.5, 0.5])
b = np.array([0.2, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0])

non_zeros = ~tf.equal(b, 0.)
cast_op = tf.cast(non_zeros, tf.float64)
new_vec = tf.multiply(a, cast_op) # won't work

# the required output is [0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0]
```

I am trying to obtain the vector `[0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0]` as explained in the code. Does anyone know how to do this? I also looked at `tf.fill` but that takes a scalar value, so won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because `tf.multiply` expects tensors of the same shape. What you could do, however, is to simply do this:

```
a = np.array[0.5, 0.5])

b = np.array([0.2, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0])

b = np.logical_and(b, n.ones(b.shape)).astype(float)

a = np.concatenate((a, np.zeros(b.shape[0] - a.shape[0])))

new_vec = a * b
```

Comment: in this case `a` has duplicate values, but there could be different values + the vector can be of variable size, but always less than or equal to the number of elements in `b`.

Comment: @i squared - Keep it Real: I've edited my post after your more precise request.

Comment: I was hoping for tensorflow ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can exploit the broadcasting capability of the `tf.multiply` op.

I've added next to every line the shape of the tensor: please note the usage of `tf.expand_dims` to add a `1` dimension to the `a` tensor in order to get, after the multiplication, a tensor with shape `(2,4)`.

This tensor has repeated values (2 rows, 4 columns equal), hence we can just take the first row

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

a = np.array([0.5, 0.5])  #(2)
b = np.array([0.2, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0])  #(4)

non_zeros = ~tf.equal(b, 0.)  #(4)
cast_op = tf.cast(non_zeros, tf.float64)  # (4)
new_vec = tf.multiply(tf.expand_dims(a, axis=[1]),
                      cast_op)  # (2, 1) * (4) = (2, 4)
new_vec = new_vec[0, :]  # (4)
print(new_vec)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

print(sess.run(new_vec))
```

This code produces `[0.5 0.5 0. 0.]`

Comment: You could replace `~tf.equal(b, 0.)` by `tf.not_equal(b, 0.)` for better readability.